# Não está plotando gráfico

Tags: python

Segue o código a seguir:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

#RECEBENDO OS DADOS EM FORMA DE LISTA
recebe = open("Exemplo.csv")
dados = csv.reader(recebe,delimiter=';')

for i in dados:
    print(i)
recebe.close()
#------------------------------------------

print("<------------------------------------------->\n")
recebe = open("Exemplo.csv")
dados = csv.DictReader(recebe,delimiter=';') #DELIMITER É COMO OS CAMPOS ESTÃO DIVIDIDOS (PODENDO SER , E ;)
idades = []
for k in dados:
    idades.append(int(k["IDADE"]))

print(idades)

#TROCANDO ULTIMO VALOR
idades[6]= 39
#---------------------------
print(idades)

faixaEtaria=["0-20","21-30","30-45","45-90"]

#(EIXO X, EIXO Y, COLOR)

pl.bar(faixaEtaria,idades,color="red")
pl.ylabel("IDADES")
pl.xlabel("FAIXA ETÁRIAS")
pl.title("GRAFICO")
pl.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparece esse erro ao compilar o codigo, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver ou me indicar a onde estou errando ?

Answer (score 2):

Acho que o tipo de gráfico que você deseja é um [histograma](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), onde será mostrada a quantidade de idades por faixa.

```
idades = [19, 20, 44, 55, 77, 88, 39]
#faixaEtaria=["0-20","21-30","30-45","45-90"]
faixaEtaria=[0,21,31,46,90]

pl.hist(idades, bins= faixaEtaria, align='mid')
pl.ylabel("IDADES")
pl.xlabel("FAIXA ETÁRIAS")
pl.title("GRAFICO")
pl.show()
```

O exemplo acima mostra o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que as faixas (parâmetros `bins`) funcionam da seguinte maneira:
Primeiro intervalo vai de `[0, 21)`, `0` incluso, mas `21` não. Na sequência, `[21,31)`, `[31,46)`. No ultimo intervalo, ambos os limites são inclusos, então temos `[46,90]`.